# Switching the order of elements on mobile devices using css

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, owl-carousel

I am designing this website haidar.ws/gar3 and I have a problem with the orders of some images on mobile view

I customized the owl slider to have a different view on mobile and I used the following css for customization

```
.fixed-hero-slider  .owl-stage {
transform: inherit !important;
transition: inherit !important;
width: 100% !important;
}

.fixed-hero-slider  .owl-item.cloned {
    display: none;
}
.fixed-hero-slider  .owl-item
{
    width : 100% !important;
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

when I remove `width: 100%` from the `.fixed-hero-slider  .owl-item` style, I find that the images are in the correct order like the following image 
[image]

but when I add it, the browser take the most right image as the first one like the following image [image]

while I want the most left one to be the first one so how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `float: right !important` to make them fall in order according to the markup.

Comment: This. Or use flexbox and feel your css-muscles swell like goku powering up to SSJ.

Comment: because it is an arabic site I need the order to be the same in web view because the user will look to the images from right to left, in english the right image is last one but in arabic it is the first one, on mobile it considers the right one the first one so it appears the first one in the mobile view

Answer (score 0):

Revert the order of images in HTML, so that currently first image would be the last — this will be your proper order for mobile view. Then, on the main **desktop view** use following css to revert this order (use `display: inline-block` instead of `float` for `.fixed-hero-slider .owl-item`, other styles remain the same):

```
.fixed-hero-slider  .owl-stage {
    direction: rtl;
}
.fixed-hero-slider  .owl-item {
    display: inline-block;
    direction: ltr;
}
```

For mobile view revert back items order and again remove `float` for `.fixed-hero-slider  .owl-item`:

```
.fixed-hero-slider  .owl-stage {
    direction: ltr;
}
.fixed-hero-slider  .owl-item {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```